# Importing BertModelLayer for Bert

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I want to import BertModelLayer for Bert but I keep getting error `ImportError: cannot import name 'BertModelLayer' from 'bert'`, I have installed bert but kept having the same error.

```
from bert import BertModelLayer
```

what is the right installation for BertModelLayer?

Comment: How did you install `bert` ? What commands?

Comment: !pip install bert

Answer (score 2):

The installation command is:

```
pip install bert-for-tf2
```

as per [PyPi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/bert-for-tf2/)

then you can use:

```
from bert import BertModelLayer
```

I am assuming that you are using tensorflow-2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a different package?

Try installing `bert-tensorflow` instead, since bert is not the name of the package.